# KILL ALIENS NOW!

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

The world has been invaded by aliens. They are everywhere killing people and taking over the world. You are hiding with your friend.

They have one weakness - the **high pitched sounds**.

You can't go yell at them, because you'd get caught before, so you remember the state had a conveniently made machine that emits a high pitched sound all over the earth, which will get rid of the aliens. The only problem is the aliens are guarding the place where the machine is and you can't possibly go there.

As your friend is an hacker, they created a program that activates the machine if you type the string `KILL ALIENS NOW!`. While they were about to type it, an alien discovered and caught 'em, throwing the **querty** keyboard on the floor. The keyboard is as show in the picture.

[image]

Somehow it still works!...well, kinda...when you type a character, the character on its right also types. So if you type 5, it will type 56. The keyboard arrows work normally and all the keys in the numpad and meta keys (print screen, etc) also work well and do nothing else.

The **delete** and **backspace** keys don't work.

Typing `shift left arrow` for example, will delete a character of code and replace it with a `z`.

Typing `j` does **not** type k, for example (this behaviour is the same for the other borbidden keys).

If you type `right shift` you will click in the `up arrow` too, for example.

The letters `k`, `i`, `l`, `a` and `n` don't work (how convenient, huh).
You decide to program the `KILL ALIENS NOW!` output, but if you do it in a lot of bytes the aliens will discover that someone is trying to break into the machine.

How will you type the string with that stupid keyboard?

## Summary of the rules

Make a program with any programming language you wish without the letters `k`, `i`, `l`, `a` and `n`, but if you type a character, it will type the one on the right too, that outputs the string `KILL ALIENS NOW!` with the least size of **bytes** possible for it to not appear in the alien's database as the current top action.

Comment: What happens if you type a key at the edge of the keyboard? Also, what are the effects of meta-characters like "Delete". Ex, if I want a \ in my program, it would have to be followed by a `Delete` key. Does that delete key get echoed as an unprintable character? Does it delete the \ I just typed? Does it do nothing?

Comment: The Backspace key is followed by Print Screen, which won't affect our code. So we can always just backspace the extra character. To type the forbidden characters, we type the key to the left, use Left Arrow (the subsequent Down Arrow won't do anything), Backspace, Right Arrow (types a 0), Backspace. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Also, is the score the number of bytes or the number of keypresses?

Comment: Nice catch! Updated it now. Delete and backspace don't work. Typing shift left arrow for example, will delete a character of code and replace it with a z. Clicking the character j for example, does **not** type k

Comment: The score is the number of bytes, as if you have a lot of them, it will appear on top of the current actions, meaning the aliens will find out about it.

Comment: How do you type programs containing unprintable characters?

Comment: That's up to you to discover!

Comment: If I press `Shift-L`, does that mean a `;` or a `:` is the next character typed? Or would the result be `L;z`?

Comment: Also, what happens if the keys used aren't on a standard keyboard? For that matter, what if they aren't on _any_ keyboard at all?

Comment: You only have the keyboard shown in the image. If you type `shift-l ;` it will type `:z`

Comment: Why is `shift` treated like it is being pressed second? Shouldn't `shift g` for example be treated as `shift z` and `g h`, resulting in `ZGH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 92 bytes

```
1290/zx:"())_QWCV*(P[CVNM	QRTUI*(RTRT	QAS:"cv'
1290/zx#$J:"12-=!@!@j!@780-m,45hjvbvbvbvbvb<>
```

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (the <kbd>Shift</kbd>key that results from this can be ignored since shift by itself does nothing) <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> (to deselect anything that may have been selected by <kbd>Shift</kbd> and its implicit <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>)<kbd>;</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>(release <kbd>Shift</kbd>)<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>(`k` is a forbidden character so is not generated)<kbd>;</kbd>(release <kbd>Shift</kbd>)<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>(release <kbd>Shift</kbd>)<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>(release <kbd>Shift</kbd>)<kbd>7</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

Note the literal tab characters on the first line.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//83NLI00K@qsFLS0NSMDwx3DtPSCIh2DvPz5QwMCgn11NIICgkK4Qx0DLZSSi5T54IqV1bxslIyNNK1VXRQdMhSdDC3MNDN1TExzcgqS4JBG7v//wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), <s>538</s> 221 byte

```
++++++++++[z>?+++++++>?++++++++++>?+++>?+<z<z<z<z-]\>?+++++./-=-=./+++././<z++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++./>?-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=./+++++++++++./-=-=-=./-=-=-=-=./+++++++++./+++++./<z./>?-=-=-=-=-=./+./++++++++./<z+./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6iq@zsoUw4A8YGEjZVEKgbGwOV1tPXtdW11dMHM/X0baq0CQA9fTt7kBZMCDYEoQwmiEUaygRZh2ocUAKhDOwaPf3//wE)

I hope it is correct...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 when i understand it right i only need the z character when i delete another and in this code i dind't delet any character but it can be that i made a mistake...

Comment: Oh, wait; right-shift exists. My bad!

Comment: After each period (.) there should be a / no?

Comment: sry my bad forget them :D

Comment: @DuarteArribas should be better now

Comment: ah! even less bytes too!

Comment: ... but still over twice the size of my answer.